# How To Backup Microsoft Azure SQL Database Using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

Good day, I am trying to backup a Microsoft Azure SQL database using an ASP.Net application programmatically into either a .BACPAC file I can download to a local machine or into an Azure blob storage platform. I know similar questions have been asked before but I have searched the web and cannot find a recent solution that seems to work. A simple "Backup database" SQL query also doesn't seem to be possible as I am constantly thrown with the error message: 'BACKUP DATABASE' is not supported in this version of SQL Server. Any help would be greatly appreciated. [Attempt at consuming API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEW8b.png)

Comment: In future please quote the `@@VERSION`. There are a lot of different SQL offerings  now.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way i think is to use [`Databases - Export Rest Api`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/databases%20-%20import%20export/export)(Exports a database to a bacpac)
 The rest api provides you with a blobUri which you can use to download or transfer to Azure blob storage

Comment: Awesome, that looks just like what I am looking for. Would you by any chance have any example code of how to consume the API?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client
this is a basic `Call a Web API From a .NET Client` tutorial. If my answer is what you were looking for then accept it.

Comment: Could you please look at the edit I made with the attached picture. I am getting an error : "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.""

Comment: storageUri should be some thing like this `"storageUri": "https://test.blob.core.windows.net/bacpacs/testbacpac.bacpac"`
You only provided location to a sub folder.
Try it with postman tool first then with c#